# highcharts column chart json data is not accepted

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

hi i am generating highchart column chart from `json` values,

i have fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ddw147/ykapQ/1/)

```
       $(function () {
          var options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Score in DIffrent exam '
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ["jan","frb"]
        },

        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },

        series:[] // [ {"name":"asd", "data": [12,13]} ]
    };

  var data=  '{"examnames":[ "demo","demo"],"scores":[ "-0.5","0.5"]}';

  parseddata =jQuery.parseJSON(data)

  console.log(parseddata.scores);

  //jQuery.parseJSON(parseddata.scores);
  options.xAxis.categories = parseddata.examnames; 
  options.series = [ {"name":"asd", "data": parseddata.scores} ]
  // options.series = [ {"name":"asd", "data": [-0.5,0.5]} ]

 $("#container").highcharts(options)

});
```

at line no `37` i am providing source for score as

```
  options.series = [ {"name":"asd", "data": parseddata.scores} ]
```

but it is not accepting but if change to

```
  options.series = [ {"name":"asd", "data": [-0.5,0.5]} ]
```

it works , but it is the same data as in parseddata.scores , i am not getting where i am getting wrong

**EDIT**
console ouput
[image: console output]

Comment: Could you add `console.log(parseddata.scores);` output to your question?

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi just added image for console output or you can see at your browser using  http://jsfiddle.net/ddw147/ykapQ/1/

Comment: Try assign your data directly to series property. Dont parse it.. After Parsejson, series values are converted to string type.

Comment: someone just answered here , he was right i need to use numeric values  instead of string

Comment: Did you try directly assigning? I mean `options.series = [ {"name":"asd", "data": data} ]`. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt work, because you have strings in data, instead of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You need the returned data  like

> [  ['08/2010',50000.00],['012/2010',80000.00]  ]